# Unable to reinitialize google maps by getting latitude and longitude from variables

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following HTML in my web page:

```
<p id="info-1"> My Title</p>
<button type="button" id="showMap-1" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Show On Map</button>
<input type="hidden" id="lat-1" value="32.3396528">
<input type="hidden" id="lon-1" value="-111.0118179">
```

And I have the following script:

```
$(document).on( 'click','button[id^="showMap-"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var arr = this.id.split('-');
    var count = arr[1];
    var latVal = $("#lat-"+count).val();
    var lonVal = $("#lon-"+count).val();
    var titleVal = $("#info-"+count).text();
    var newCenter = {lat: latVal, lng: lonVal};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: newCenter});
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: newCenter, map: map, title: titleVal});
});
```

I am trying to reinitialize the google map based on the selected location. But I get the following error:

> InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in
>   property lat: not a number

But the same script works if I set the values directly

```
var latVal = -25.344;
var lonVal = 131.036;
var titleVal = "test";
var newCenter = {lat: latVal, lng: lonVal};
var map = new google.maps.Map(
document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: newCenter});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: newCenter, map: map, title: titleVal});
```

I have to set the values dynamically and reinitialize the map based on the selected location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, the `latVal` and `lonVal` are not numbers. They are string.

You can convert the string to number by putting `+` before the strin. Like:

```
var latVal = +$("#lat-"+count).val();
var lonVal = +$("#lon-"+count).val();
```

.. Or you can also use `parseFloat()` like:

```
var latVal = parseFloat( $("#lat-"+count).val() );
var lonVal = parseFloat( $("#lon-"+count).val() );
```